# How to enable the click to all looping images separately

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I creating the blog page, i looping the like button images according the total count of post using PHP example:(Facebook like button) here i'm facing the issues is php while loop is working but when i click first post image only working with click animation if i click second post like button also first post button only working i can't understand what is the issues. Please advice me or give solution how to fix this issues. i attached my code down.

```css
  svg {
        cursor: pointer;
        overflow: visible;
        width: 60px;
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: -45px;
    }
    
    svg #heart {
        transform-origin: center;
        animation: animateHeartOut .3s linear forwards;
    }
    
    svg #main-circ {
        transform-origin: 29.5px 29.5px;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins {
        display: none;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #heart {
        transform: scale(0.2);
        fill: #ddd810;
        animation: animateHeart .3s linear forwards .25s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #main-circ {
        transition: all 2s;
        animation: animateCircle .3s linear forwards;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp1 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp1 #oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(0, -30px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp1 #oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(10px, -50px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp2 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp2 #oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(30px, -15px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp2 #oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(60px, -15px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp3 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp3 #oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(30px, 0px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp3 #oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(60px, 10px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp4 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp4 #oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(30px, 15px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp4 #oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(40px, 50px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp5 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp5 #oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(-10px, 20px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp5 #oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(-60px, 30px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp6 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp6 #oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(-30px, 0px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp6 #oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(-60px, -5px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp7 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp7 #oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(-30px, -15px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp7 #oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(-55px, -30px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp2 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s opacity .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp3 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s opacity .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp4 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s opacity .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp5 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s opacity .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp6 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s opacity .3s;
    }
    
    #checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp7 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s opacity .3s;
    }
    
    @keyframes animateCircle {
        40% {
            transform: scale(10);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: #ddd810;
        }
        55% {
            transform: scale(11);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: #ddd810;
        }
        65% {
            transform: scale(12);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: #ddd810;
        }
        75% {
            transform: scale(13);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: transparent;
            stroke: #ddd810;
            stroke-width: .5;
        }
        85% {
            transform: scale(17);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: transparent;
            stroke: #ddd810;
            stroke-width: .2;
        }
        95% {
            transform: scale(18);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: transparent;
            stroke: #ddd810;
            stroke-width: .1;
        }
        100% {
            transform: scale(19);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: transparent;
            stroke: #ddd810;
            stroke-width: 0;
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes animateHeart {
        0% {
            transform: scale(0.2);
        }
        40% {
            transform: scale(1.2);
        }
        100% {
            transform: scale(1);
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes animateHeartOut {
        0% {
            transform: scale(1.4);
        }
        100% {
            transform: scale(1);
        }
    }
```

```html
    <?php
                                           while($getPerPost=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result01))
     {  
       extract($getPerPost);
    ?>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-ins"/>
          <label for="checkbox-ins">
            <svg id="heart-svg<?php echo $p_id; ?>" viewBox="467 392 58 57" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
            <g id="Group" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(467 392)">
        <path d="M25.82,40.35a1.67,1.67,0,0,0,.31.94l.94,1.36a1.8,1.8,0,0,0,1.36.73h3.24A1.76,1.76,0,0,0,33,42.65L34,41.29a1.69,1.69,0,0,0,.32-.94v-2H25.92A13.27,13.27,0,0,0,25.82,40.35Zm-5-14.53a9.11,9.11,0,0,0,2.3,6.06,14.75,14.75,0,0,1,2.72,                                                                                      4.81h8.36a16,16,0,0,1,2.72-4.81,8.92,8.92,0,0,0,2.3-6.06,9.2,9.2,0,0,0-18.4,0ZM30,21.64a4.19,4.19,0,0,0-4.18,4.18.9.9,0,0,                                                                                     1-.84.84.89.89,0,0,1-.83-.84A5.84,5.84,0,0,1,30,20a.89.89,0,0,1,.84.83A.9.9,0,0,1,30,21.64Z" id="heart" fill="#AAB8C2"/>                                                                            <circle id="main-circ" fill="#ddd810" opacity="0" cx="29.5" cy="29.5" r="1.5"/>
        <g id="grp7" opacity="0" transform="translate(7 6)">                                                                              <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="6" r="2"/>                                                                             <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="5" cy="2" r="2"/>
        </g>
        <g id="grp6" opacity="0" transform="translate(0 28)">                                                                              <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="7" r="2"/>
        <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="3" cy="2" r="2"/>
        </g>
        <g id="grp3" opacity="0" transform="translate(52 28)">                                                                               <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="7" r="2"/>                                                                            <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="4" cy="2" r="2"/>
        </g>
        <g id="grp2" opacity="0" transform="translate(44 6)">                                                                              <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="5" cy="6" r="2"/>                                                                             <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>                                                                         </g>
        <g id="grp5" opacity="0" transform="translate(14 50)">                                                                    <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="6" cy="5" r="2"/>                                                                             <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>                                                                         </g>
        <g id="grp4" opacity="0" transform="translate(35 50)">                                                                             <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="6" cy="5" r="2"/>                                                                            <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>                                                                          </g>
        <g id="grp1" opacity="0" transform="translate(24)">                                                                                <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2.5" cy="3" r="2"/>                                                                                <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="7.5" cy="2" r="2"/>                                                                          </g>
        </g>
        </svg>
        </label>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't change your svg class, instead you should generate unique classes for inputs and link them with labels. 
Also you should change all id selectors to class selectors, since your input isn't alone anymore.
Here's updated fiddle with two working buttons:

```css
  svg {
        cursor: pointer;
        overflow: visible;
        width: 60px;
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: -45px;
    }
    
    svg #heart {
        transform-origin: center;
        animation: animateHeartOut .3s linear forwards;
    }
    
    svg #main-circ {
        transform-origin: 29.5px 29.5px;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #heart {
        transform: scale(0.2);
        fill: #ddd810;
        animation: animateHeart .3s linear forwards .25s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #main-circ {
        transition: all 2s;
        animation: animateCircle .3s linear forwards;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp1 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp1 #oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(0, -30px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp1 #oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(10px, -50px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp2 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp2 #oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(30px, -15px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp2 #oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(60px, -15px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp3 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp3 #oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(30px, 0px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp3 #oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(60px, 10px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp4 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp4 #oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(30px, 15px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp4 #oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(40px, 50px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp5 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp5 #oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(-10px, 20px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp5 #oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(-60px, 30px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp6 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp6 #oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(-30px, 0px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp6 #oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(-60px, -5px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp7 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp7 #oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(-30px, -15px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp7 #oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(-55px, -30px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp2 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s opacity .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp3 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s opacity .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp4 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s opacity .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp5 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s opacity .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp6 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s opacity .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp7 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s opacity .3s;
    }
    
    @keyframes animateCircle {
        40% {
            transform: scale(10);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: #ddd810;
        }
        55% {
            transform: scale(11);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: #ddd810;
        }
        65% {
            transform: scale(12);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: #ddd810;
        }
        75% {
            transform: scale(13);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: transparent;
            stroke: #ddd810;
            stroke-width: .5;
        }
        85% {
            transform: scale(17);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: transparent;
            stroke: #ddd810;
            stroke-width: .2;
        }
        95% {
            transform: scale(18);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: transparent;
            stroke: #ddd810;
            stroke-width: .1;
        }
        100% {
            transform: scale(19);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: transparent;
            stroke: #ddd810;
            stroke-width: 0;
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes animateHeart {
        0% {
            transform: scale(0.2);
        }
        40% {
            transform: scale(1.2);
        }
        100% {
            transform: scale(1);
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes animateHeartOut {
        0% {
            transform: scale(1.4);
        }
        100% {
            transform: scale(1);
        }
    }
```

```html
           <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-ins" id="input1"/>
          <label for="input1">
            <svg id="heart-svg" viewBox="467 392 58 57" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
            <g id="Group" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(467 392)">
        <path d="M25.82,40.35a1.67,1.67,0,0,0,.31.94l.94,1.36a1.8,1.8,0,0,0,1.36.73h3.24A1.76,1.76,0,0,0,33,42.65L34,41.29a1.69,1.69,0,0,0,.32-.94v-2H25.92A13.27,13.27,0,0,0,25.82,40.35Zm-5-14.53a9.11,9.11,0,0,0,2.3,6.06,14.75,14.75,0,0,1,2.72,                                                                                      4.81h8.36a16,16,0,0,1,2.72-4.81,8.92,8.92,0,0,0,2.3-6.06,9.2,9.2,0,0,0-18.4,0ZM30,21.64a4.19,4.19,0,0,0-4.18,4.18.9.9,0,0,                                                                                     1-.84.84.89.89,0,0,1-.83-.84A5.84,5.84,0,0,1,30,20a.89.89,0,0,1,.84.83A.9.9,0,0,1,30,21.64Z" id="heart" fill="#AAB8C2"/>                                                                            <circle id="main-circ" fill="#ddd810" opacity="0" cx="29.5" cy="29.5" r="1.5"/>
        <g id="grp7" opacity="0" transform="translate(7 6)">                                                                              <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="6" r="2"/>                                                                             <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="5" cy="2" r="2"/>
        </g>
        <g id="grp6" opacity="0" transform="translate(0 28)">                                                                              <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="7" r="2"/>
        <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="3" cy="2" r="2"/>
        </g>
        <g id="grp3" opacity="0" transform="translate(52 28)">                                                                               <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="7" r="2"/>                                                                            <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="4" cy="2" r="2"/>
        </g>
        <g id="grp2" opacity="0" transform="translate(44 6)">                                                                              <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="5" cy="6" r="2"/>                                                                             <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>                                                                         </g>
        <g id="grp5" opacity="0" transform="translate(14 50)">                                                                    <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="6" cy="5" r="2"/>                                                                             <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>                                                                         </g>
        <g id="grp4" opacity="0" transform="translate(35 50)">                                                                             <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="6" cy="5" r="2"/>                                                                            <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>                                                                          </g>
        <g id="grp1" opacity="0" transform="translate(24)">                                                                                <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2.5" cy="3" r="2"/>                                                                                <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="7.5" cy="2" r="2"/>                                                                          </g>
        </g>
        </svg>
        </label>
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-ins" id="input2"/>
          <label for="input2">
            <svg id="heart-svg" viewBox="467 392 58 57" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
            <g id="Group" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(467 392)">
        <path d="M25.82,40.35a1.67,1.67,0,0,0,.31.94l.94,1.36a1.8,1.8,0,0,0,1.36.73h3.24A1.76,1.76,0,0,0,33,42.65L34,41.29a1.69,1.69,0,0,0,.32-.94v-2H25.92A13.27,13.27,0,0,0,25.82,40.35Zm-5-14.53a9.11,9.11,0,0,0,2.3,6.06,14.75,14.75,0,0,1,2.72,                                                                                      4.81h8.36a16,16,0,0,1,2.72-4.81,8.92,8.92,0,0,0,2.3-6.06,9.2,9.2,0,0,0-18.4,0ZM30,21.64a4.19,4.19,0,0,0-4.18,4.18.9.9,0,0,                                                                                     1-.84.84.89.89,0,0,1-.83-.84A5.84,5.84,0,0,1,30,20a.89.89,0,0,1,.84.83A.9.9,0,0,1,30,21.64Z" id="heart" fill="#AAB8C2"/>                                                                            <circle id="main-circ" fill="#ddd810" opacity="0" cx="29.5" cy="29.5" r="1.5"/>
        <g id="grp7" opacity="0" transform="translate(7 6)">                                                                              <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="6" r="2"/>                                                                             <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="5" cy="2" r="2"/>
        </g>
        <g id="grp6" opacity="0" transform="translate(0 28)">                                                                              <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="7" r="2"/>
        <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="3" cy="2" r="2"/>
        </g>
        <g id="grp3" opacity="0" transform="translate(52 28)">                                                                               <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="7" r="2"/>                                                                            <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="4" cy="2" r="2"/>
        </g>
        <g id="grp2" opacity="0" transform="translate(44 6)">                                                                              <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="5" cy="6" r="2"/>                                                                             <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>                                                                         </g>
        <g id="grp5" opacity="0" transform="translate(14 50)">                                                                    <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="6" cy="5" r="2"/>                                                                             <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>                                                                         </g>
        <g id="grp4" opacity="0" transform="translate(35 50)">                                                                             <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="6" cy="5" r="2"/>                                                                            <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>                                                                          </g>
        <g id="grp1" opacity="0" transform="translate(24)">                                                                                <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2.5" cy="3" r="2"/>                                                                                <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="7.5" cy="2" r="2"/>                                                                          </g>
        </g>
        </svg>
        </label>
```

Comment: if i pass the id for label for animation not working. i tried that

Comment: <label for="checkbox-ins" id="checkbox-ins<?php echo $p_id; ?>"> i did like that but same first image animation only working

Comment: ok, I see. Your animations are linked to `#checkbox-ins:checked+label`. Try changing id selector to class in your css and markup.
in your css change all `#checkbox-ins` to `.checkbox-ins` and in your markup `id="checkbox-ins"` to `class="checkbox-ins"`.
However you still need to generate unique id's for inputs and pass them to labels

Comment: Yes there only that issues is coming if ichange the label id same time css value also have to change then it will work i think, it's possible to change like that

Comment: <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-ins<?php echo $p_id; ?>" class="checkbox-ins"/> i did like that and i changed the css file #checkbox-ins to .checkbox-ins then also some animation not working

Comment: Some? That means that some do? Did you changed your labels `for="checkbox-ins<?php echo $p_id; ?>` too?
And are you sure that have changed all selectors in your css?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186528/discussion-between-jerad-and-elijah-ellanski).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186579/discussion-between-jerad-and-elijah-ellanski).

Comment: it's possible way to contact you please tell

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54529293/how-to-enable-the-image-view-for-all-looping-images-separately - Please check this link i have issues in that also

Answer (score 1):

As @Elijah Ellanski touches on in his answer, the issue is related to your use of id's.

You are not supposed to have multiple instances of the same id, they need to be unique. By refactoring your code (both html and css) to use classes instead and using unique id's where necessary, you can solve this problem.

Here is my suggestion:

```css
svg {
        cursor: pointer;
        overflow: visible;
        width: 60px;
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: -45px;
    }
    
    svg .heart {
        transform-origin: center;
        animation: animateHeartOut .3s linear forwards;
    }
    
    svg .main-circ {
        transform-origin: 29.5px 29.5px;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .heart {
        transform: scale(0.2);
        fill: #ddd810;
        animation: animateHeart .3s linear forwards .25s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .main-circ {
        transition: all 2s;
        animation: animateCircle .3s linear forwards;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp1 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp1 .oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(0, -30px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp1 .oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(10px, -50px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp2 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp2 .oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(30px, -15px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp2 .oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(60px, -15px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp3 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp3 .oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(30px, 0px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp3 .oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(60px, 10px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp4 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp4 .oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(30px, 15px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp4 .oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(40px, 50px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp5 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp5 .oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(-10px, 20px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp5 .oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(-60px, 30px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp6 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp6 .oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(-30px, 0px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp6 .oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(-60px, -5px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp7 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s all .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp7 .oval1 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(-30px, -15px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: .5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp7 .oval2 {
        transform: scale(0) translate(-55px, -30px);
        transform-origin: 0 0 0;
        transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp2 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s opacity .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp3 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s opacity .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp4 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s opacity .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp5 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s opacity .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp6 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s opacity .3s;
    }
    
    .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg .grp7 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .1s opacity .3s;
    }
    
    @keyframes animateCircle {
        40% {
            transform: scale(10);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: #ddd810;
        }
        55% {
            transform: scale(11);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: #ddd810;
        }
        65% {
            transform: scale(12);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: #ddd810;
        }
        75% {
            transform: scale(13);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: transparent;
            stroke: #ddd810;
            stroke-width: .5;
        }
        85% {
            transform: scale(17);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: transparent;
            stroke: #ddd810;
            stroke-width: .2;
        }
        95% {
            transform: scale(18);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: transparent;
            stroke: #ddd810;
            stroke-width: .1;
        }
        100% {
            transform: scale(19);
            opacity: 1;
            fill: transparent;
            stroke: #ddd810;
            stroke-width: 0;
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes animateHeart {
        0% {
            transform: scale(0.2);
        }
        40% {
            transform: scale(1.2);
        }
        100% {
            transform: scale(1);
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes animateHeartOut {
        0% {
            transform: scale(1.4);
        }
        100% {
            transform: scale(1);
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-ins<?php echo $p_id; ?>" class="checkbox-ins"/>
          <label for="checkbox-ins<?php echo $p_id; ?>">
            <svg id="heart-svg<?php echo $p_id; ?>" viewBox="467 392 58 57" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
            <g class="Group" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(467 392)">
        <path d="M25.82,40.35a1.67,1.67,0,0,0,.31.94l.94,1.36a1.8,1.8,0,0,0,1.36.73h3.24A1.76,1.76,0,0,0,33,42.65L34,41.29a1.69,1.69,0,0,0,.32-.94v-2H25.92A13.27,13.27,0,0,0,25.82,40.35Zm-5-14.53a9.11,9.11,0,0,0,2.3,6.06,14.75,14.75,0,0,1,2.72,                                                                                      4.81h8.36a16,16,0,0,1,2.72-4.81,8.92,8.92,0,0,0,2.3-6.06,9.2,9.2,0,0,0-18.4,0ZM30,21.64a4.19,4.19,0,0,0-4.18,4.18.9.9,0,0,                                                                                     1-.84.84.89.89,0,0,1-.83-.84A5.84,5.84,0,0,1,30,20a.89.89,0,0,1,.84.83A.9.9,0,0,1,30,21.64Z" class="heart" fill="#AAB8C2"/>                                                                            <circle class="main-circ" fill="#ddd810" opacity="0" cx="29.5" cy="29.5" r="1.5"/>
        <g class="grp7" opacity="0" transform="translate(7 6)">                                                                              <circle class="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="6" r="2"/>                                                                             <circle class="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="5" cy="2" r="2"/>
        </g>
        <g class="grp6" opacity="0" transform="translate(0 28)">                                                                              <circle class="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="7" r="2"/>
        <circle class="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="3" cy="2" r="2"/>
        </g>
        <g class="grp3" opacity="0" transform="translate(52 28)">                                                                               <circle class="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="7" r="2"/>                                                                            <circle class="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="4" cy="2" r="2"/>
        </g>
        <g class="grp2" opacity="0" transform="translate(44 6)">                                                                              <circle class="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="5" cy="6" r="2"/>                                                                             <circle class="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>                                                                         </g>
        <g class="grp5" opacity="0" transform="translate(14 50)">                                                                    <circle class="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="6" cy="5" r="2"/>                                                                             <circle class="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>                                                                         </g>
        <g class="grp4" opacity="0" transform="translate(35 50)">                                                                             <circle class="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="6" cy="5" r="2"/>                                                                            <circle class="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>                                                                          </g>
        <g class="grp1" opacity="0" transform="translate(24)">                                                                                <circle class="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2.5" cy="3" r="2"/>                                                                                <circle class="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="7.5" cy="2" r="2"/>                                                                          </g>
        </g>
        </svg>
        </label>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/a4sb7kv6/

Answer (score 0):

```css
    svg {
            cursor: pointer;
            overflow: visible;
            width: 60px;
            margin: 0;
            margin-bottom: -45px;
        }
        
        svg #heart {
            transform-origin: center;
            animation: animateHeartOut .3s linear forwards;
        }
        
        svg #main-circ {
            transform-origin: 29.5px 29.5px;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins {
            display: none;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #heart {
            transform: scale(0.2);
            fill: #ddd810;
            animation: animateHeart .3s linear forwards .25s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #main-circ {
            transition: all 2s;
            animation: animateCircle .3s linear forwards;
            opacity: 1;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp1 {
            opacity: 1;
            transition: .1s all .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp1 #oval1 {
            transform: scale(0) translate(0, -30px);
            transform-origin: 0 0 0;
            transition: .5s transform .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp1 #oval2 {
            transform: scale(0) translate(10px, -50px);
            transform-origin: 0 0 0;
            transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp2 {
            opacity: 1;
            transition: .1s all .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp2 #oval1 {
            transform: scale(0) translate(30px, -15px);
            transform-origin: 0 0 0;
            transition: .5s transform .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp2 #oval2 {
            transform: scale(0) translate(60px, -15px);
            transform-origin: 0 0 0;
            transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp3 {
            opacity: 1;
            transition: .1s all .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp3 #oval1 {
            transform: scale(0) translate(30px, 0px);
            transform-origin: 0 0 0;
            transition: .5s transform .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp3 #oval2 {
            transform: scale(0) translate(60px, 10px);
            transform-origin: 0 0 0;
            transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp4 {
            opacity: 1;
            transition: .1s all .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp4 #oval1 {
            transform: scale(0) translate(30px, 15px);
            transform-origin: 0 0 0;
            transition: .5s transform .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp4 #oval2 {
            transform: scale(0) translate(40px, 50px);
            transform-origin: 0 0 0;
            transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp5 {
            opacity: 1;
            transition: .1s all .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp5 #oval1 {
            transform: scale(0) translate(-10px, 20px);
            transform-origin: 0 0 0;
            transition: .5s transform .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp5 #oval2 {
            transform: scale(0) translate(-60px, 30px);
            transform-origin: 0 0 0;
            transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp6 {
            opacity: 1;
            transition: .1s all .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp6 #oval1 {
            transform: scale(0) translate(-30px, 0px);
            transform-origin: 0 0 0;
            transition: .5s transform .3s;
        }
        
       .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp6 #oval2 {
            transform: scale(0) translate(-60px, -5px);
            transform-origin: 0 0 0;
            transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp7 {
            opacity: 1;
            transition: .1s all .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp7 #oval1 {
            transform: scale(0) translate(-30px, -15px);
            transform-origin: 0 0 0;
            transition: .5s transform .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp7 #oval2 {
            transform: scale(0) translate(-55px, -30px);
            transform-origin: 0 0 0;
            transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp2 {
            opacity: 1;
            transition: .1s opacity .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp3 {
            opacity: 1;
            transition: .1s opacity .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp4 {
            opacity: 1;
            transition: .1s opacity .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp5 {
            opacity: 1;
            transition: .1s opacity .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp6 {
            opacity: 1;
            transition: .1s opacity .3s;
        }
        
        .checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp7 {
            opacity: 1;
            transition: .1s opacity .3s;
        }
        
        @keyframes animateCircle {
            40% {
                transform: scale(10);
                opacity: 1;
                fill: #ddd810;
            }
            55% {
                transform: scale(11);
                opacity: 1;
                fill: #ddd810;
            }
            65% {
                transform: scale(12);
                opacity: 1;
                fill: #ddd810;
            }
            75% {
                transform: scale(13);
                opacity: 1;
                fill: transparent;
                stroke: #ddd810;
                stroke-width: .5;
            }
            85% {
                transform: scale(17);
                opacity: 1;
                fill: transparent;
                stroke: #ddd810;
                stroke-width: .2;
            }
            95% {
                transform: scale(18);
                opacity: 1;
                fill: transparent;
                stroke: #ddd810;
                stroke-width: .1;
            }
            100% {
                transform: scale(19);
                opacity: 1;
                fill: transparent;
                stroke: #ddd810;
                stroke-width: 0;
            }
        }
        
        @keyframes animateHeart {
            0% {
                transform: scale(0.2);
            }
            40% {
                transform: scale(1.2);
            }
            100% {
                transform: scale(1);
            }
        }
        
        @keyframes animateHeartOut {
            0% {
                transform: scale(1.4);
            }
            100% {
                transform: scale(1);
            }
        }
```

```html
<?php
                                                   while($getPerPost=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result01))
             {  
               extract($getPerPost);
            ?>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-ins" class="checkbox-ins<?php echo $p_id; ?>"/>
                  <label for="checkbox-ins<?php echo $p_id; ?>">
                    <svg id="heart-svg<?php echo $p_id; ?>" viewBox="467 392 58 57" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
                    <g id="Group" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(467 392)">
                <path d="M25.82,40.35a1.67,1.67,0,0,0,.31.94l.94,1.36a1.8,1.8,0,0,0,1.36.73h3.24A1.76,1.76,0,0,0,33,42.65L34,41.29a1.69,1.69,0,0,0,.32-.94v-2H25.92A13.27,13.27,0,0,0,25.82,40.35Zm-5-14.53a9.11,9.11,0,0,0,2.3,6.06,14.75,14.75,0,0,1,2.72,                                                                                      4.81h8.36a16,16,0,0,1,2.72-4.81,8.92,8.92,0,0,0,2.3-6.06,9.2,9.2,0,0,0-18.4,0ZM30,21.64a4.19,4.19,0,0,0-4.18,4.18.9.9,0,0,                                                                                     1-.84.84.89.89,0,0,1-.83-.84A5.84,5.84,0,0,1,30,20a.89.89,0,0,1,.84.83A.9.9,0,0,1,30,21.64Z" id="heart" fill="#AAB8C2"/>                                                                            <circle id="main-circ" fill="#ddd810" opacity="0" cx="29.5" cy="29.5" r="1.5"/>
                <g id="grp7" opacity="0" transform="translate(7 6)">                                                                              <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="6" r="2"/>                                                                             <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="5" cy="2" r="2"/>
                </g>
                <g id="grp6" opacity="0" transform="translate(0 28)">                                                                              <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="7" r="2"/>
                <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="3" cy="2" r="2"/>
                </g>
                <g id="grp3" opacity="0" transform="translate(52 28)">                                                                               <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="7" r="2"/>                                                                            <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="4" cy="2" r="2"/>
                </g>
                <g id="grp2" opacity="0" transform="translate(44 6)">                                                                              <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="5" cy="6" r="2"/>                                                                             <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>                                                                         </g>
                <g id="grp5" opacity="0" transform="translate(14 50)">                                                                    <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="6" cy="5" r="2"/>                                                                             <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>                                                                         </g>
                <g id="grp4" opacity="0" transform="translate(35 50)">                                                                             <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="6" cy="5" r="2"/>                                                                            <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>                                                                          </g>
                <g id="grp1" opacity="0" transform="translate(24)">                                                                                <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2.5" cy="3" r="2"/>                                                                                <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="7.5" cy="2" r="2"/>                                                                          </g>
                </g>
                </svg>
                </label>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
```